# How to pass object from parent to child class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass an object from the parent to the child class. I make a GET request with axis, where I get the object, then I set the response of the request as `this.state.contact` in my parent class. Until there all seems good, if I console.log the contact in state it shows up correctly.

The object looks like this when output in the console:
`{first_name: "Test", last_name: "surname", email: "test@hotmail.com", phone_number: "7228732837", slug: "testhotmailcom"}` and if I console log `typeof this.state.contact` it prints `Object`

In my child class I just take `this.props.contact` assign it to `this.state.data` and console log it in the render method. However, the console prints `undefined`.

How can I pass this object from the parent class into the child class? I need to set the states in the child class with the props as I will need to render a form with these values.

Here are both classes:

Parent class:

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import UpdateContact from './UpdateContact';

export default class Test extends React.Component {
    state = {
        contact: ''
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const slug = this.props.match.params.slug
        const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/contacts/" + slug + ".json"

        axios.get(url)
            .then( (resp) => {
                const contact = resp.data.data.attributes
                this.setState({ contact })
            })
            .catch( data => {
                debugger
            })
    }

    render() {
     return(
            <div>
                <UpdateContact contact={this.state.contact}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Child class:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class UpdateContact extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: this.props.contact
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {console.log(this.state.data)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You set that in the constructor so you just get the initial state. Usually you would just use this.props.contact in your child component. If you need it as a state you could use a shouldcomponentupdate to set the state using this.setState

Comment: Both classes are extending React.Component. If the UpdateContact class is, indeed, a child class of your Test class, then your child class should extend your parent class.

Comment: @RobH he seems to be using parent/child to imply containment rather than inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State initialization is run only once when component is mounted and the props.contact is undefined yet. That is why you got undefined in your render.

You need to add `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method if you want to update your child component state based on props

```js
  componentDidUpdate(prevProp) {
    if (this.props.contact !== prevProps.contact) {
      this.setState({ data: this.props.contact });
    }
  }
```

The other thing is that if you don't need to change `this.props.contact` in your Child component, it's way better to use the prop directly instead of setting state which is not gonna change internally.

Comment: I have added this componentDidUpdate method, but now it throws an error:
`Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Comment: Have you addded it to the Child component?

Comment: sorry I foorgt about the condition, please check my answer again

Comment: tit is still giving me the same error, sees like the error gets thrown in the parent class (Test) when I do the axios request in this line `this.setState({ contact })` and it gets catched as the debugger is stopping there

Comment: it works with the `prevProp` thank you @r4mka !!